# Index into a Python iterator

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I have an iterator `iterator` and a list of indices `indices` (repeats possible) and I want to extract just those elements from my iterator. At the moment I'm doing

```
indices = sorted(indices)
deltas = [indices[0]] + [indices[i+1] - indices[i] for i in range(len(indices) - 1)]
output = []
for delta in deltas:
    for i in range(delta):
        datum = next(iterator)
    output.append(datum)
```

Are those two layers of loop necessary? Am I missing a trick with `itertools`?

Comment: Yeah, you need to give some sort example that helps us reproduce what you are trying to accomplish. I presume indices is some list of `int`s, but this line: `indices[0] + [indices[i+1] - indices[i] for i in range(len(indices) - 1)]` will not work if that is the case - you can't add a `list` to an `int`.

Comment: Also, indices implies some sort of sequence type. `iterators` are for a single pass over a sequence: if you are going to be repeating indices why not *index directly into the sequence*?

Comment: I can't think of anything that would be a clear improvement over your code. `itertools` functions like `islice` won't work for you since you may have repeated indices. One thing to consider though: if the `iterator` contains only a modest amount of data (not more than can fit in memory, and not orders of magnitude more than the number of indices), it might be easier to simply consume it all to populate a list, and use a trivial list comprehension to get the requested values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't need the double loop as you can do this with a single loop and without creating deltas but the check code becomes more complicated:

```
it = iter(sorted(indices))
index = next(it)
for i, datum in enumerate(iterator):
    if i != index:
        continue
    output.append(datum)
    try:
        index = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

You can also do this in a list comprehension for very low number of indices as you incur overhead for the check (but avoid the `sort`):

```
[datum for i, datum in enumerate(x) if i in indices]
```

You can reduce the cost of the check by converting `indices` to a `set`. I would be interested to see performance of `sort` over a `set` construction (set lookup is O(1)):

```
indices = set(indices)
[datum for i, datum in enumerate(x) if i in indices]
```

First and third options are roughly equivalent in timing at just over 900 ms (slight edge to first) to choose 1000 random indices out of 10,000,000 items. The OP's code ran in about 1.2 s.

Answer (score 0):

If memory isn't a constraint, I would just find the max index and prepopulate an array of iterator values up to that max index.  You're going to have to compute the intermediate values anyway, so you really don't gain anything by computing the deltas.

```
max_index = max(indices)
data = [v for v in itertools.islice(iterator, max_index + 1)]
values = [data[i] for i in indices]
```